# Password hashing for safe storage with Argon

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, authentication, hashcode

This code snippet implements password hashing for safe storage. It uses Argon2 as hashing algorithm. The method `hash_password()` is used to hash and salt a password. The method `verify()` is used to check whether a password matches a hash.

#### Initial setup:

```
pip install argon2-cffi
```

#### Code:

```
from argon2 import PasswordHasher
from argon2.exceptions import VerifyMismatchError

def hash_password(password):
    ph = PasswordHasher()
    pw_hash = ph.hash(password)
    return pw_hash

def verify(pw_hash, password):
    ph = PasswordHasher()
    try:
        return ph.verify(pw_hash, password)
    except VerifyMismatchError:
        return False

def main():
    pw_hash = hash_password('s3cr3t')
    print(pw_hash)
    print(verify(pw_hash, 's3cr3t'))
    print(verify(pw_hash, 's3cr4t'))
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

1- Do you think the implementation of hash_password is up-to-date and secure?

2- Do you think the implementation of verify is up-to-date and secure?

3- Would you make any other changes to this code snippet?

4- Did you use any additional resources while checking the code? If yes, please provide a link or description of your resource

Answer (score 4):

Argon2 is a decent choice of hash. Well done for following the most important rule of cryptography, and letting someone else design and implement the cryptography!

There are a few minor style things which I'd change about your code:

- I'd return the hash immediately instead of assigning it to a variable.
- I'd avoid an explicit `return None` from a function which just drops off the end.
- The guidance in the documentation for your argon2 library says to call `check_needs_rehash` alongside verify, so that may want exploring. It's a key part of ensuring that you stay up-to-date and secure.
- Depending on the context in which you're running this code, and in particular if you're likely to be running it in an already multi-threaded environment like many web servers, I'd be tempted to dial back the `parallelism` parameter to the `PasswordHasher` object.
- This isn't a problem in practice when you're just using the defaults, but because `PasswordHasher` could be parameterised you may want to put a bit more thought into ensuring the hashing and verification objects match. For example, you could use a singleton pattern or a common function.